# What's the best way to connect to Sphero bolt on windows 10 and connect to it with javascript without using Sphero edu app?

Tags: sphero, bolt

[image]

I'm trying to connect to Sphero Bolt on windows 10. When I select Add a Bluetooth Device, I can see the device name `SB-058A`.However, it keeps spinning and shows `Connecting` when I select it.
I have installed [Sphero edu app](https://edu.sphero.com/) and could connect to Sphero Bolt via the edu app. 
My end goal is using [spherojs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sphero) and connect to Sphero Bolt on windows 10.

What's the best way to connect to Sphero bolt on windows 10 and connect to it with javascript without using Sphero edu app?

Answer (score 0):

The Sphero BOLT communication is not based on UART. It uses custom BLE services. That means you can't connect to it the way you tried.

You would have to explore and implement communication services yourself (or use a 3rd party library, if you found some). The Sphero company hasn't published their BLE protocol as far as I know. However, the communication is possible and you can find a few resources on the net you can start with.

The packet structure is public (https://sdk.sphero.com/docs/api_spec/general_api) and many commands are compatible with older Sphero versions (V2). However, there are some differences.

Google these GUIDs to find more:
00010001-574f-4f20-5370-6865726f2121
00020001-574f-4f20-5370-6865726f2121